# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype') error with react-notion-x

Tags: javascript, next.js13, notion-api

##### Description

I am trying to render data from Notion using the `react-notion-x` library in my Next.js project. However, I am getting an error that says "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')". This error occurs when the `react-notion-x` library is loaded.

##### Steps to Reproduce

1. Install the `react-notion-x` library in a Next.js project.
2. Use the `NotionRenderer` component to render data from a Notion page.
3. Run the project and observe the error that occurs.

##### Expected Behavior

The `NotionRenderer` component should render the data from the Notion page without any errors.

##### Actual Behavior

The following error occurs when the `react-notion-x` library is loaded:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prototype')
```

##### Notion Test Page ID

i got from the documentation
`067dd719a912471ea9a3ac10710e7fdf`

##### Screenshots

[image]

##### Additional Information

I have tried reinstalling the `react-notion-x` library and updating it to the latest version, but the error still occurs. I have also checked that I am providing all the required props to the `NotionRenderer` component and that the data structure is correct.

this is the code I used

```
import Container from "@/components/elements/Container"
import PageHeading from "@/components/elements/PageHeading"
import BackButton from "@/components/elements/BackButton"
import { NotionRenderer } from "react-notion-x"
import { NotionAPI } from 'notion-client'

const notion = new NotionAPI()

export default async function ProjectDetailPage({ params }) {
  
  const recordMap = await notion.getPage('067dd719a912471ea9a3ac10710e7fdf')
  console.log(recordMap)
  
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <BackButton />
        <PageHeading title="" />
        <NotionRenderer recordMap={recordMap} fullPage={true} darkMode={false} />
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

and these are the depedencies used

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.0",
    "@jridgewell/sourcemap-codec": "^1.4.15",
    "@notionhq/client": "^2.2.13",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-popover": "^1.0.7",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.0.0",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "framer-motion": "^10.16.4",
    "lucide-react": "^0.279.0",
    "next": "^13.5.4",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "nextjs-toploader": "^1.4.2",
    "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
    "notion-client": "^6.16.0",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-icons": "^4.11.0",
    "react-notion-x": "^6.15.6",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.14.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "usehooks-ts": "^2.9.1",
    "zustand": "^4.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "latest",
    "eslint": "latest",
    "eslint-config-next": "latest",
    "postcss": "latest",
    "tailwindcss": "latest"
  }
```

Comment: Looks like something to do with bebel and nextjs
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44584

Comment: It might caused by version. You are using notion-client version ^6.16.0, but the latest version is ^2.2.13. Try do ```npm uninstall notion-client``` and ```npm install notion-client@2.2.13```